# Can you connect to MySQL database without providing pure credentials in Python code?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, encryption

Is there a way to connect to MySQL DB with maybe RSA keys or by providing SHA-256 encrypted login and password in code? Because let's say we want to post our app publicly. Anyone who can decompile the app will see all the code including our login and password to the database.

I was wondering (**purely theoretically**) because If I wanted to implement some kind of codes system (like those from gift cards or PaySafeCards) to my app so the user could have like a premium membership or different feature and I wanted to store them in my database then someone could just decompile the app, steal the login and password that were in code, access the database, steal the codes and have the membership for free so **how would I prevent a situation like that from happening?**

Comment: you have always  to decrypt the credentials and so you have to include the means to decrypt it before sending it. Do it like all app developers, so use a server side script to get the data and you can communicate through https with it

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about it. That seems so simple actually. Thanks.
Also, what would be the best encryption? I guess that something like SHA-256 or AES-256 would not work because you can't decrypt those hashes just like that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use environment variables. Check [this website](https://www.nylas.com/blog/making-use-of-environment-variables-in-python/) to learn more. You will use the os module and more specifically os.environ which returns a dictionary that contains all current environment variables.

If you want to publish your code on a public platform such as Github you can set private environment variables. Check [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables)

Comment: But will this app be usable for other users? (will the app connect to the database on their computers and maybe different systems?). Aren't the environment variables saved on local PC? And if not then could the users access them?